# Even display of unevenly spaced numbers on x/y coordinates

Tags: r, ecdf

Would you advise on how I could make an even display of unevenly spaced number on a graph. For example, considering the code below :

```
BREAKS = c(0, 0.1, 1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500)

a <- seq(0,100,0.1)

b <- seq(0,1000,0.1)

plot(ecdf(a), col="red", xlim=c(0,100), main=NA, breaks=BREAKS)

plot(ecdf(b), col="green", xlim=c(0,100), add=T, breaks=BREAKS)
```

I would like to show on X-axis (0, 0.1, 1 and 10) spaced in an equal/even manner.

Comment: @Bogdan try `?axis()` or `?text()` If using base R